# Owl Carousel and Elementor Page Builder full width Problem

Tags: slider, owl-carousel, elementor

When I create custom widgets of elementor with owl-carousel. after when i use it in full width. then it create left site. not middle.

[image]

Comment: The issue is with section. When you use carousel it add specific widths to elements of slider so the parent section in which the slider is present should have overflow hidden selected

Answer (score 0):

Take a  look at your js init. is there something like "margin: 25" ? delete it. otherwise, I guess, it could be css. do you have a testing link?